# python selenium select a new element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to make a list of tweets using selenium and I am having trouble with selecting the next element after I record the first one. This is my code:

```
while count < tweets:
            sleep(1)
            ActionChains(self.twitterDriver).scroll_to_element(self.twitterDriver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]')).perform()
            tweet = self.twitterDriver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]')
            self.tweets.loc[len(self.tweets.index), "tweet"] = tweet.text
            count +=1
```

there are multiple elements with `xpath` of `//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]` and I can't figure out how to move to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the markup but if I understand you correctly you want to retrieve all elements with an xpath of `//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]`.
If this is the case, you just need to use the `find_elements` instead of `find_element` and it will return a list of all elements that you can then use in a simple for loop.

```py
tweets = self.twitterDriver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@data-testid="tweetText"]')
for tween in tweets:
   ...
```

Comment: Would that find all the tweets on the page or is it limited to just the tweets that are currently loaded on the screen?

Comment: I did not test it, but assuming that the tweets are loaded on demand when scrolling, you would only see the ones currently on the page.